# Does it make sense to have more data records than participants in a study?

Tags: regression, correlation, modeling, descriptive-statistics

I have a sample size of 51 and for my each participant, I have 15 dichotomous variables for vocabulary knowledge (know-not know) and 15 variable for their score for each word. Something like this:

```
     table     table score
P1   0              41
P2   1              55
P3   0              37  
P4   1              52
```

I have 15 different pairs of variables like this and I restructured the data into long format (variables to cases). So now I have 2 main variables as "words" and "scores". I will go for pearson correlation but this time "N" increases to thousands. I have 51 participants, not thousands of people. Is that a problem or normal? I think it is quite reasonable but I am not sure.

Comment: Exactly what will you be computing the correlation for?  What do you hope it will reveal?

Comment: I have 15 different words. My participants have taken a test on these words if they know their meaning or not. Then they involved in an eye teacking session. I wonder if there is a relationship between knowing a word and how long it is fixated in miliseconds. Each word is dihotomous variable, how long it is fixated is continuous. I want to execute a single correlation test, not 15 different bivariation.

Comment: That is an example of a *regression* problem.  Pearson correlation will tell you little of any value.  A very great amount concerning this question has been posted on our site (thousands of posts). Take a look at this [tightly narrowed search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=multiple%20regression%20categorical%20continuous%20-logistic%20-interaction%20answers%3a1) for some ideas and then broaden the search if you don't find the answers you seek.

Comment: I scrutinized the topics yet I could not find an exact answer. It seems like a linear regression, however I have 15 continuous outcomes and 15 dichotomous predictors. Then do I have to conduct 15 different regressions for each variable? Rather than this, I need a single regression and a single analysis for all these variables.

Comment: In your earlier comments it sounds like you wish to explore 15 relationships, one for each word. This could be performed as 15 separate analyses. However, if you believe there exists a common underlying relationship, then you would conduct a *single* regression analysis between test results and eye-fixation durations (in which the specific word might enter as a covariate). This would be much more appropriate, powerful, and useful than computing a bunch of Pearson correlation coefficients.

Comment: Thanks whuber, I solved the issue, I computed eye fixation average for 15 variables as fixation variable and also took mean for their answers which became an exam score variable. Then I conducted linear regression with these two variables, the results seem quite nice now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where in your database have you recorded the participant identifier?  That is crucial.